# Integrar um plugin jQuery a um tema WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou usando o [Nivo Slider](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider) no meu site a partir do exemplo básico oferecido pelo plugin. No arquivo `header.php` do *theme* coloco os scripts e o `<div>` com as imagens apontando pra um diretório do *theme*. E no `footer.php` a inicialização do slider.

Mas como posso fazer essa integração do plugin jQuery seguindo os padrões do WordPress e passar informação dinamicamente? No caso do slider, imagens.

**`header.php`**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nivo/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nivo/nivo-slider.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!-- mais código -->    
</head>    
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nivo/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
    <a href="http://example.com"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nivo/toystory.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nivo/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/nivo/walle.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**`footer.php`**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        // nivoslider init
        jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'boxRainReverse',
            slices:15,
            boxCols:8,
            boxRows:8,
            animSpeed:500,
            pauseTime:5000,
            directionNav:false,
            directionNavHide:false,
            controlNav:true,
            captionOpacity:1
        });
    });
</script>
```

<sub><sub>*Pergunta e respostas inspiradas na Q&A [jQuery(…).nivoSlider is not a function in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22436214/1287812).*</sub></sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A primeira observação é que [*é mais indicado criar um plugin*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web)<sup>(en)</sup> e fazer com que essa funcionalidade seja [*independente do tema*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php)<sup>(en)</sup>, assim, ao mudar de tema, é muito mais fácil fazer a migração do Slider.

A segunda é que *só devemos usar outras versões de jQuery* <sup>(em vez da que vem embutida no WordPress)</sup> *se soubermos o que estamos fazendo*. Isso evita conflitos com outros plugins e temas.
A falta de cuidado ao usar jQuery corretamente no WP é [responsável por inúmeros problemas](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=jquery%20not%20working)<sup>(en)</sup> e *bugs*.

O plugin que segue é a adaptação do código da pergunta, observando o seguinte:

- Como sempre, o ponto de partida é o código do [**Plugin Base Demo**](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204) <sup>(do moderador @toscho no WordPress Developers)</sup>. É uma base [oop](/questions/tagged/oop) limpa e pronta pra rodar.
- **Estrutura dos arquivos** do plugin. Os arquivos marcados em cinza provêem do próprio plugin Nivo Slider.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **Principais funções** do WordPress [`plugins_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url), [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), [`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) e [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).
- Conferir o **uso de scripts como dependências**. Nosso arquivo personalizado (`nivo-start`) é carregado usando como dependencias um arquivo registrado (`nivo-pack`) e o jQuery embutido no WP.
- Conferir o **uso do `$` como atalho para `jQuery`** no arquivo `start-nivo.js`.
- O **Slider é usado como Shortcode**, apontando para algum post ou página específica. Aqui, por exemplo, justo após o `<body>` no arquivo `header.php` do *theme* ativo:

  ```php
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[teste-nivo id="105"]'); ?>
  ```
- Para organizar os slides pode-se usar um *Custom Post Type*, onde cada post conteria uma galeria de imagens para fazer sliders; ou então uma categoria de Posts; ou uma Página *master* com várias filhas. Faça o upload das imagens, a Legenda e a Descrição correspondem ao `post_excerpt` e `post_content` do arquivo anexado.
- O método privado **`get_nivo_page($id)`** renderiza o HTML a partir da `$id` passada pelo Shortcode.
- O método privado **`get_nivo_default()`** faz o *output* da `string` HTML dentro do Shortcode é construido usando a [**sintaxe Heredoc**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) do PHP. **Atenção para o identificador de fechamento**: o `HTML;` final *não deve ter **nenhum** espaço em branco antes do identificador*.

Arquivo `meu-nivo-slider.php`:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Nivo Slider
 * Plugin URI:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9546/201
 * Description: Adaptação do exemplo básico do Nivo Slider como plugin de WordPress
 * Author:      brasofilo
 * License:     GPLv3
 */

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( B5F_Nivo_Slider::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class B5F_Nivo_Slider
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $plugin_url = '';
    public $plugin_path = '';

    /**
     * Acessar a instancia de trabalho deste plugin.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @return  object of this class
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Usado para iniciar os trabalhos normais do plugin.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @return  void
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'teste-nivo', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Deixado publico e vazio intencionalmente.
     *
     * @see plugin_setup()
     */
    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Carregar scripts e styles
     *
     * @wp-hook wp_enqueue_scripts
     */
    public function enqueue () 
    {
        wp_register_script( 
             'nivo-pack',
             $this->plugin_url . 'js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js'
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nivo-start', $this->plugin_url . 'js/start-nivo.js', array( 'jquery', 'nivo-pack' ), false, true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'nivo-css', $this->plugin_url . 'css/nivo-slider.css' );
    }

    /**
     * Criar HTML para o Shortcode
     *
     * @wp-hook add_shortcode
     */
    public function shortcode( $atts ) 
    {
        // Shortcode definiu uma ID de post, eg, [teste-nivo id="NUMERO"]
        if( isset( $atts['id'] ) )
            $output = $this->get_nivo_page( $atts['id'] );
        
        // ID não fornecido, usar template do demo
        else
            $output = $this->get_nivo_default();
        
        return $output;
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepara o HTML puxando os attachments do post com $id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function get_nivo_page( $id )
    {
        $attachments = get_children( array(
            'post_parent' => $id, 
            'post_status' => 'inherit', 
            'post_type' => 'attachment', 
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        ));
        if( $attachments )
        {
            $output = '<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';
            foreach( $attachments as $attach )
            {
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach->ID, 'full' );
                $output .= sprintf(
                    '%s<img src="%s" alt="" title="%s" />%s',
                    empty( $attach->post_content ) ? '' : "<a href='$attach->post_content'>",
                    $image[0],
                    empty( $attach->post_excerpt ) ? '' : $attach->post_excerpt,
                    empty( $attach->post_content ) ? '' : '</a>'
                );
            }
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
        else
            $output = '<h2>Faça upload de imagens no post/página!</h2>';
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Prepara o HTML usando o código demonstrativo do Nivo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function get_nivo_default()
    {
        $nivo_folder = $this->plugin_url . 'img';
    
        $output = <<<HTML
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="$nivo_folder/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
            <a href="http://example.com"><img src="$nivo_folder/toystory.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
            <img src="$nivo_folder/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
            <img src="$nivo_folder/walle.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
            <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
        </div>  
HTML;
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Arquivo `start-nivo.js`:

```php
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) // $ como atalho de jQuery
{ 
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'random',           
        slices: 15,                 
        boxCols: 8,                 
        boxRows: 4,                 
        animSpeed: 500,             
        pauseTime: 3000,            
        startSlide: 0,              
        directionNav: true,         
        controlNav: true,           
        controlNavThumbs: false,    
        pauseOnHover: true,         
        manualAdvance: false,       
        prevText: 'Anterior',           
        nextText: 'Seguinte',           
        randomStart: false
    });
});
```

Comment: e +1 por mostrar a maneira mais profissional, além do link para a base de plugin, vlw!

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do Brasofilo com certeza é a maneira mais profissional de se fazer isso, para apenas integrar o nivoslider no tema, você deverá carregar os arquivos nescessários através das funções do wp.

Em function.php faça insira o seguinte.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'os_meus_scripts' );

function os_meus_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.nivo.slider.pack', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nivo/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js', true );
    wp_register_script( 'nivo-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nivo/nivo.js', true ); // esse é o arquivo com a chamada.

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // carrega o jquery nativo do wp
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.nivo.slider.pack');
    wp_enqueue_script('nivo-js');

    // carrega o css do nivo
    wp_register_style( 'nivo-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/nivo/nivo-slider.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'nivo-css' );
}
```

Repare que essa é a maneira que você deverá carregar qualquer script ou estilo no seu tema. Também usamos:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

para carregar o jquery nativo do wordpress e assim evitar conflito.

Dentro de js/nivo/nivo-js.js vai o seguinte conteúdo.

```
$(function(){ // chamada short-hand para o ready();
    var options = {
        effect: 'boxRainReverse',
        slices:15,
        boxCols:8,
        boxRows:8,
        animSpeed:500,
        pauseTime:5000,
        directionNav:false,
        directionNavHide:false,
        controlNav:true,
        captionOpacity:1
    };

    $('#slider').nivoSlider(options);
});
```