# Como inserir um REQUIRE nesta função?

Tags: php, wordpress, actions

Como insiro um `require` nesta função Wordpress para menu na administração?

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    # $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function = '', $icon_url = '', $position = null
    add_menu_page (
        'Gerência de dados',
        'Gerência',
        'manage_options',
        'gerencia_de_dados',
        function(){ 
            echo '<h2>Sistema de gerenciamento de traduções</h2>';
            echo '<form><input type="text"></form>'; 
        },
        'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        6
    );
});
```

O resultado atual para fins de aprendizado é este:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Você já está aqui há um bom tempo, por favor, dê uma olha nesses links http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?lq=1 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%c3%adtulo

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do Bruno Augusto. Não é recomendado usar globais, mas também não é o fim do mundo (o WP mesmo está cheio delas), então no arquivo principal do plugin:

```
$my_plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
$my_plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    add_menu_page (
        [...]
        function(){ 
            global $my_plugin_path;
            include $my_plugin_path . '/folder/file.php'; 
        },
        [...]
    );
});
```

E dentro de `file.php`:

```
 global $my_plugin_url;
 $imagem = $my_plugin_url . 'img/file.png';
```

Se quiser fazer com OOP, [aqui tem um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9546/201). Com isso, dentro do *included file* você usaria:

```
$imagem = B5F_Nivo_Slider::get_instance()->plugin_url . 'img/file.png';
```

---

Já adiantando, certamente vai precisar carregar JS e CSS na sua página:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    $hook = add_menu_page ( [...] );
    add_action( "admin_print_styles-$hook", 'admin_jscss_sopt_34639');
});

function admin_jscss_sopt_34639() {
    global $my_plugin_url;
    wp_enqueue_style( [...] );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-js', $my_plugin_url . 'js/file.js' );  
}
```

Comment: O WP é tão cheio de globais que uma vez eu me vali dessa falha de design dele pra encaixar um MVC com roteamento de URL dentro do Painel Administrativo dele. XD

Answer (score 2):

O quinto argumento de [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page), apesar de definido como função é, na verdade, um [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), ou seja, qualquer função ou método de classe invocável pelo PHP no contexto da API do WordPress.

Você optou por uma [Closure](https://www.php.net/Closure), um objeto interno que representa uma função anônima. Quando o item adicionado ao menu for clicado, esse argumento invocável, se definido, será executado.

Isso significa que, caso o conteúdo a ser exibido por essa entrada do menu se encontre num arquivo externo, ou outras coisas mais complexas que fugiriam ao escopo da pergunta, basta que seja feito o include/require dentro dessa função anônima:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    # $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function = '', $icon_url = '', $position = null
    add_menu_page (
        'Gerência de dados',
        'Gerência',
        'manage_options',
        'gerencia_de_dados',
        function(){ 
            include 'path/to/file.php'; 
        },
        'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        6
    );
});
```

O maior dos seus problemas, aqui, nem é onde invocar o include/require e sim localizar o arquivo. Para isso [get_template_directory()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) pode ajudar.